# Questions from dead users should not be editable

Tags: feature-request, historical-lock

In connection with the fifth anniversary of Aaron Swartz's death, there is a [discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16122999) on Hacker News that goes like this:

*codeulike* says:

> This StackOverflow question from Aaron about using rsync to download and copy lots of files is like a piece of history frozen in time. [keep rsync from removing unfinished source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491/keep-rsync-from-removing-unfinished-source-files).

*meagar* says:

> Please remember that Stack Overflow does not welcome any kind of meta commentary about a question's author in that question's comments or answers.

*switch007* says:

> And of course someone added a revision just now, for some minor style tweaks.

*klez* says:

> Also, the editor is a SO moderator

Here is the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48491/revisions) in question.

I think all of the above raises important questions:

- Should questions or answers be locked when a person dies?
- Should there be some sort of status indicator beside the name of a dead user?

I propose this solution:

- When a user dies, other users on the site should be able to mark the user as `potentially gone`. This could be done with a form where options could be: "I know this person is dead", "I believe this person is gone", "I know this person will not come back to Stackoverflow", but the status set on the user would still be `potentially gone`.
- The `potentially gone` status is hidden to everyone but users that are moderators. Or it could be visible to users that have a certain amount of points.
- A moderator should be able to remove the `potentially gone` status.
- If the user has not logged in after two years, and the user has been marked as `potentially gone`, the account is marked as `historical`.
- Accounts that are marked as `historical` have a little clock right next to the username. If the clock is clicked, a short explanation that the user appears to be gone shows up. There is no need to go into details for why the user is gone, there is no need to claim that the person is dead or not.

To sum it up, these are the two new user statuses I propose:

- `potentially gone`
- `historical`

And posts from `historical` users should not be editable.

Comment: And I thought the focus of this site is on Q&A and not _so_ much on users...

Comment: Uber-harassment: declare user dead ...

Comment: If a user is marked as `potentially gone` and the status is not visible to other users (or the user itself), how is that harassment?

Comment: What benefit would this have? Stack Overflow is not a social network. It's about content more than it is about its users. Posts are editable so they can be improved and updated; why should that change through the death of their original author, and why would it matter whether they are dead (extremely rare at this moment, due to the site's users' average age) or just otherwise gone from the site (far more widespread)?

Comment: I appreciate the motive here, this is something very sweet that you're trying to do for someone. But I don't agree with Questions/Answers being locked, we still need to be able to update and amend questions, regardless of the metaphysical presence of their original poster. Also, being able to declare other users as deceased would cause no end of spam and trouble for those who have to review these. Plus the possibility of living users being marked as dead etc.

Comment: Pekka, one benefit would be to know if you could expect to get an answer from that user, ever.

Comment: There are potentially very valid edits that should/could be made to posts by users who are no longer with us or participating on the site. Stopping those doesn't benefit Stack Overflow or future users in any way.

Comment: bluefeet, if a user has been gone for two years, are there really valid edits that have not been made in those two years, that could be made?

Comment: If you want to honour a user somehow then perhaps you could leave your username and password to someone else in your will so that if you die they can update your bio? Of course, that only works if you prepare before hand...

Comment: `one benefit would be to know if you could expect to get an answer from that user, ever` You *already* don't have a guarantee you will receive an answer from any user you interact with. Loads and loads of users, alive and well but rude people that they are, never respond to answers or requests for clarification. The good thing about the way Stack Overflow is designed is that, differently from, say, Facebook, this doesn't matter as much - anyone else with something meaningful to add can jump in at any moment.

Comment: `if a user has been gone for two years, are there really valid edits that have not been made in those two years, that could be made?` absolutely. Technologies evolve; a new product or library may have been published; someone may have worked out a solution to a problem in the meantime... that's the whole point of Stack Overflow's editing system.

Comment: @Alexander Yes,it's possible they were missed

Comment: honk, a subtle clock icon next to a username together with locked questions is not too much of a distraction from questions and answers, I think. There has to be some user-management, even when Q&A is the focus.

Comment: `There has to be some user-management, even when Q&A is the focus.` I'm still not seeing a powerful argument *why*, though. Deaths of prominent users are arguably  a rare exception that  can be perfectly handled manually by moderator intervention - something that would probably be needed even if this feature existed.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for the feedback guys.

Comment: A few months ago community updated links in all posts to https.. wonder what would have happened with the lock in place

Comment: @Suraj Rao, I'm not suggesting locking the URL, but the contents.

Comment: I get that.. content can have references and links within posts. Community updated those. But I guess this would go tangential..

Comment: If I were dead, I would prefer that my content would stay untouched. If I would have to choose between someone editing or deleting my content, I would choose deletion. Users should own their content, even on a QA site like Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Alexander If you want to have full control over your content, and to prohibit others from making any type of edit to the post ever, then you shouldn't post on SO, because SO's rules specifically indicate that certain types of edits are considered acceptable, and that such edits will be made *even if the author doesn't want them to be*.  Likewise, by posting the content to SO you have licenced the content such that anyone (including SO) is able to publish that content (as long as it's properly cited), meaning you can't demand it be deleted.

Comment: @Alexander the one benefit I can (maybe) stand behind is the 'you know the user is unlikely to come back'. But even if we agree this is a benefit (which far from everybody will stand behind), locking questions has nothing to do with this. Aaron posted here to help others. Isn't keeping his content up to date and as helpful as possible a better legacy than keeping his words as is (which arguably the revision history does ANYWAY)?

Comment: *And of course someone added a revision just now, for some minor style tweaks.* I like how they're complaining that a mod rolled back a pointless edit, restoring the question back to its original format (save for one contemporaneous tag edit).

Comment: In his house on Stack Overflow, dead Aaron Swartz lies coding. That is not dead which can upvoted lie, and with new releases even death may die.

Comment: @Will WILL SOMEBODY THINK OF THE CHILDREN?!

Comment: @Patrice I'm not sure I can forgive the missed opportunity for a pun there by omitting the second "WILL".

Comment: @Servy, if edits are made *even if the author doesn't want them to be*, then the author can delete all his content when alive, but the author's wishes will not be respected when he/she is dead. I think this is a bug, and that authors should have the option to delete their content upon death.

Comment: @Alexander You've made the false assumption that you can just delete all of your content while you're still alive.  You can't.  If you try to vandalize your own quality content by deleting it, an automated site processes, or if necessary, a moderator, will stop you.  So no bug.

Comment: @Servy, I see, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the question is edited again at UTC 2019-07-08 13:16:57Z.

Comment: User dead , but his/her Questions and Answer still alive

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a bad idea.

The entire point of Stackoverflow is to focus on the questions and answers, and keeping them relevant through editing, not the users that post them.

I think the usefulness of peer reviewed improvements through editing is an important part of the site, and I don't think just because someone is dead or no longer participates in the site that we should stop doing that. The goal is to *always* keep the Q/A relevant and as good as possible.

Comment: That said, you could protect that specific question from edits, due to historical reasons?