# What happens to an account after you die?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, developer-story, users, accounts

What happens to Stack Overflow accounts when the owner dies? Is there a process for marking an account In Memoriam and allowing an account of someone who has died to remain for as long as Stack Overflow exists?

Facebook has a Memorialized account process https://www.facebook.com/help/150486848354038/ and I am wondering if Stack Overflow has something similar.

I think it would be kind of cool to have my Stack Overflow account up for years and years after I die and decades from now someone finds a question or an answer I have posted interesting.

Comment: cross site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled

Comment: There was a proposal last year to indicate accounts of users who had passed away, but it was bundled together with requests to [lock all their posts and prevent editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361809/7795130) which, as you can expect, was heavily disagreed with since we aren't a social network like Facebook.

Comment: You can abandon your account, and your questions and answers will live on and people will be able to vote for them. Nothing needs to be done to your account if you die.

Comment: the same happen if you simply decide to no more be active on SO

Comment: We are not a social network. We focus on the content, not the accounts. Accounts can be abandoned for any reason, and all that happens is that they no longer contribute to the collection of content we have. That’s very different from Facebook, which focuses on connecting people.

Comment: Although I must admit, with how antisocial I am, I'm probably more social and have a more meaningful connection to users here than I do on any social media platform I have an account on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters while the focus may be on content that does not preclude SO being a social network as well. What's the purpose of having a Profile or a Developer Story or having a log of Activity with badges? These are all contributors towards being a social network, of having relationships within the SO framework.

Comment: @RichardChambers: no, they are not. Badges are ways to teach how the site works and to gamify, to get you to contribute to the site. The dev profile is part of the monetisation of the site; employers pay to get access to potential new hires.

Comment: Seems like you're conflating the *question* of what happens with a new *feature* for when it happens. At some level, there's no functional difference between an account which is abandoned and an account formerly controlled by someone who's deceased. The only thing the site concerns itself with are the artifacts produced when the account was active.

Comment: I want my profile to be pretty much the same, except prefaced with "Hi, I'm dead!" Change present-tense statements to past-tense that begin with, "When I was alive..." And replace my image with a skull that looks like it's smiling. Smiles are contagious.

Comment: @ScottHannen You could write a program that will change your profile to "Hi, I'm dead!" unless you click a button once a week or something. That's a good idea I might do that...

Comment: @JasonC Seein as it's pretty much inevitable we could all just save ourselves the time and add that to our profile right now.

Comment: How about a "well played" gold badge..?

Comment: @JasonC it adds new meaning to the "Late Answers" queue

Comment: We should have a *"press "F" to pay respects"* section then when the user presses `F`, it should show a nice animation that lasts for about 6-8 seconds.

Comment: _a "well played" gold badge_ Yup. And a silver _upgraded_ and a bronze _deprecated_ one.

Comment: When I pass, I'm going to have "In disk sleep awaiting reincarnation server" on my profile. Dangit, first thing Monday and I'm already designing a watchdog to do that for me if I ever fail to get a yearling badge.

Comment: I'd like to be reincarnated and answer my own question.

Comment: I think that at the current rate of software evolution, decades from now most of the current content will be irrelevant.

Comment: This question should start with "I have died. What happens to my account now?"

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm not so sure that the current content won't remain relevant. Some content may become more relevant as people maintaining old software refer to the content in order to understand the code and implementation of that old software. My impression is that there is a lot of code that exists and just works until suddenly it doesn't because of some environmental change or because it is being ported to a new environment. I wonder if decades from now people will be running virtual machines with Windows Server 2016 because porting code for critical services is just too expensive.

Comment: @JasonC Someone's been watching too much Black Mirror.

Comment: The Eternal Question Ban

Comment: @LogicalBranch And during Winter Bash, it removes your hat for a few seconds.

Comment: Hi. I'm not really a living person. I'm a ghost that helps keep this site clean! I do things like: Haunting the souls of the question banned to help them repent, Escorting shredded spammers to the realms beyond, Occasionally downvoting old, well-received posts to keep the abuse scripts tuned.

Comment: Perhaps the avatar could have the word "Deceased" stamped across it, with a sight upward sloping angle for effect.

Comment: Worry about today ... :)

Comment: Sorry, but I read *died yesterday* instead of *asked yesterday* ⚰️⚰️

Comment: I wonder how much of the content here has been made by people already deceased. It's probably impossible to quantify that really.

Comment: I like to think that your account becomes a force ghost. Much like @RobertColumbia is.

Comment: When I die, I would like my reputation points to be evenly distributed between new users that sign up that day, with the writing "A gift from Elysium".

Comment: Eventually, given enough time, there will be more dead-user accounts than live-user accounts.  Do you really want to see "This user is deceased" most of the time when you go to look at a user's profile?  I'm all for reflecting on our fleeting mortality, but perhaps not every single workday!

Comment: I think it would be more of a concern if someone didn't die.

Comment: @Bohemian: when I die I want to have a laptop computer, hooked to an above-ground solar charger, placed into the casket with me, the screen open, powered up, and with my fingers upon the keys. I mean, seriously, I don't care about coming back from the dead (what the heck - sleep all night, sleep all day: what's not to love?) - but I *do* want to keep up with Stack Overflow. :-)

Comment: make your password easy, to remember in next life

Comment: Some loser that cares about reputation points on meta will mark your post as a duplicate and it will get deleted. ;)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This has happened. We've come to know about it through reading the news like anyone else, or by having the user's co-workers contact us to let us know. On the *public* site, we don't do anything. The account (and thus attribution) to all of their contributions remain normalized.

If we're contacted by a *verifiable family member*, we can sometimes make some accommodations on a case-by-case basis depending on the needs and goals, but we can't offer any guarantee. This gets especially tricky if the scenario presents internationally. But, we have no plans to have a system in place where designated accounts can take certain actions.

***On a Team or Enterprise instance, however, it's up to the administrator.***

The part of an account that's linked to an account on a team would be left to whatever the organizational policy of that team says. That's .. not up to us. But, the two presences are completely separate for those kinds of concerns.

> I think it would be kind of cool to have my Stack Overflow account up for years and years after I die and decades from now someone finds a question or an answer I have posted interesting.

Me too. And I think you can fully expect future "digital archaeologists" to really appreciate the perspective your contributions lend, and the database dumps to the Internet Archive essentially *guarantee* that all contributions that remained visible for at least a few months become potential time capsules in a hundred years or so.

Kinda ... humbling :) It's something I often think about.

Comment: yep I think about this too and am relieved I have FB friends from this site. I keep my FB open to others posting on my timeline if I die, that way I figure someone will tell the folks on here. [FWIW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193530)

Comment: The one reason I can think of for a death notice would be so that if someone attempts a comment to the writer of a post or comment there would be a message indicating the writer's death. That way the person doing the comment won't be expecting a response any time soon.

Comment: Now I want to write a script that would auto-reply to all @mentioned comments to me with some message along the lines of, "Sorry, I can't post from beyond the grave."

Comment: @RichardChambers It wouldn't have to be specific to death though; you could just show an alert on inactive accounts -- "this user hasn't logged in for X days/years/etc; their account may be abandoned and you may not get a response from them."

Comment: You can imagine other benefits too. For instance, making it permanently impossible to log in to the specified account. It could be really upsetting to friends/family if an account of a deceased person was hacked and suddenly became active again.

Comment: The problem will be likely more and more relevant with the decades. Reacting the posts of unfortunately deceased people will get away worthy volunteer effort from the system. Even if you have no plan for it today, I suggest to consider to do something in the future.

Comment: We don't deal with Information deprecation very well across the board, which means we fail to consider quite a few signals that certain questions or answers fell out of relevance and shouldn't have emphasis in site searches (or search engines) any longer. We also have to solve the issue of folks being reticent to make _major_ edits to something when it becomes actively harmful, because they essentially need to rewrite the post. This is part of that (increasingly) urgent need for strategy. Fortunately, we're still ahead of it, for _now_ anyway.

Comment: *"This gets especially tricky if the scenario presents internationally"* - hmm, why? If you're just making ad-hoc accommodations, what does the location or nationality of anyone involved matter?

Comment: @SteveBennett Especially if the deceased has diamond mod privileges.

Answer (score 10):

*(NB: this answer has been reformulated substantially since the initial downvotes)*

Stack Exchange sites are not a social network, but they are still a community.  Some members of a community are outstanding, leading members, contributing unlike most others.  We are honouring such users while alive by reputation, badges, and special posts on meta when they're the first to reach a major milestone.  I would like to be part of a community where, if such a user passes away, we take a moment of contemplation in the form of a meta post and put an obituary notice on their user page.  For example, see [this user on Christianity SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1039/affable-geek) (who still tops the reputation leagues four years after he passed away), also active on other sites on the network.  I would find it sad (and frankly disrespectful) if all we can see is that a top user (suddenly) stops contributing, leaving the community to speculate what happened.

The large majority of users are unknown to most others, and such a notice would be noise and too much work to maintain (with 10 million users, dozens to hundreds of users die daily).  Compare how famous people deaths are announced in the news, not "ordinary" people's death.

Comment: I know that on meta, downvotes indicate disagreement — but I'm curious what part people disagree with.  The first paragraph, the second, or both?

Comment: Why do you think that many people would want to do anything with an account here other than just close it down? I am guessing that Stack Exchange sites don't come into most peoples minds when dealing with death as there is much less here memory wise than on a site like facebook. And besides I don't think it will be the mods dealing with it but the employees and having a policy in place could make it easier for them.

Comment: @JoeW I think that if someone has contributed massively to a site, then the least the site can do if they pass away is to have a modest in memoriam, "you will be missed".  Such obituaries serve a basic human need. Not of the deceased, who has no more needs, but of the rest of the community. I find that the linked example has done this well. Stack Exchange is not a social network, but it is still a community, in particular on meta.

Comment: I am not saying they should or shouldn't just that I don't think that the demand for something like this will be that big. On the other hand even if someone does contribute a lot it should be up to their family (or what they informed their family of before hand) on the decision to do it which means that someone needs to reach out to SE before anything happens.

Comment: @JoeW Should it be up to the family?  If a colleague dies, or a friend at the sports club, do the colleagues or friends need permission from the family to print or post their own obituary notice?  That's an interpersonal skills question and perhaps culture dependent, but I'm not sure that I would need permission from the family to publicly express that I miss someone.

Comment: Because printing an obituary is different than memorializing an account online which has both large personal impact and legal issues which only family can properly sign-off on. Just because you are a colleague or friend doesn't mean you have any say at all in what happens to their online presence after they die.

Comment: @JoeW Why does it not? Does an online community need permission from the family (legally or morally) to post an online notice that a prominent member has sadly passed away? Does the family inherit the "right to be forgotten" under GDPR? [I have asked](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/42747/3569) for I wouldn't know of any legal issues here (I am not a lawyer).

Comment: This isn't a simple online community but a full fledge business that has to follow many different privacy laws regarding its users and as such could get into big trouble if they just did something like that at the whim of someone who claimed to be a friend/colleague. And yes family or who ever is legally designated does gain all sorts of legal rights about the deceased.

Comment: @JoeW I think you misunderstand me.  I never considered the scenario of someone claiming a friend of colleague reaching out and requesting this.  I'm thinking of the scenario of exactly like the example I linked.  Can Stack Exchange really get into legal trouble for the linked example?  Seriously?

Comment: Depending on who did it and how the family feels about such things I would say yes.

Comment: "Stack Exchange sites are not a social network" great to know, so I won't be obligated to fill that in my US visa application

Answer (score 8):

I think at the very least SE should permanently lock the accounts of those known to be deceased. If such an account was hacked and appeared to become active again it could be extremely disconcerting for those that knew the person and it would be disrespectful to the deceased to say the least.

Comment: No. Zombies, vampires, and any other kind of revenant shouldn't have their account access curtailed in any way. #undead_welcoming

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes for this. I don't see any negative aspect to this?

Comment: @MartinSmith apparently it’s unfriendly to the nonexistent undead and that’s more important than respecting the actual dead.

Comment: @MartinSmith maybe because forever is a long time. There will be many other Martin Smiths in the centuries to come who might prefer if accounts became reusable? (I don't know if this is the reason, I'm just speculating.)

Comment: @craq user names are not unique. there are already plenty Martin Smiths. https://stackoverflow.com/users

Answer (score 6):

> I think it would be kind of cool to have my Stack Overflow account up for years and years after I die and decades from now someone finds a question or an answer I have posted interesting.

The content license requires everyone to print author names and link to user profile page. I take it that this implicitly means that there must be user profile pages as long as content from them is published and your name will be displayed next to the content produced by you as well. Someone finding a question or answer from you will know it's from you.

> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/

Comment: When accounts are deleted that users content is not always deleted with the account and when that happens there is no longer a profile page to link to.

Comment: @JoeW Giving proper attribution seems to be difficult under these circumstances. Maybe one could link to an archived version of the profile page then.

Comment: The same case presents for disassociated posts. I fail to remember if they remain ownerless, or if the community user takes ownership. Either way attribution is at least vague in such circumstance. On the other hand that is the consequence of deletion and/or disassociation. So you choose to sign your content away by doing any such action. (Except the case you are deleted off the site for moderation reasons ofcourse)

Comment: @Luuklag One can either link to profile pages that do not exist anymore or one could link to archived versions of the profile pages. Just searched for my profile page on the internet archive and the most recent version there is from March 2019.

Comment: But when a post is disassociated I don't think you can find the original author.

Comment: @Luuklag but isn't a post only disassociated at the request of the author? In which case, it shouldn't be an issue.