# How about the ones who left us, but were so much help to us in this community?

Tags: discussion

I can not describe how much I'm thankful to stack overflow community.

In few words, you strange people who I have never met, set me free to a great life.

so THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE THINGS YOU DO.

[Rudy Velthuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95954/rudy-velthuis) died two years ago next May, he was a very active member of this community.
the guy was not even a professional programmer, but he helped many others on their daily tasks. including giving me years of experience for free.

Today I would humbly ask you to add something to the accounts of those who left us. I'm no person to have great ideas on this subject, but I would really love to see some gesture for these gems that left us.

a thank you banner from the company to these people on their accounts would be the most respectable thing I would think of.

I know the site is supposed to be a library of Q&A, but these are the ones who wrote it.

And just to jump ahead of the crowd, I'm not suggesting Facebook foolishness. the banner will help new users to avoid adding any comments to those answers and questions asking the user for info. because he is dead.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Closely related: [*What happens to an account after you die?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386951/2751851); [*How should a user's death be handled?* (MSE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38742/242059).

Comment: *"will help new users to avoid adding any comments to those answers and questions asking the user for info."* - Often times comments can be answered by anyone, not only the OP, so this isn't relevant. *"I'm not suggesting Facebook foolishness."* - Memorialised accounts are places where memories can be kept and revisited. Calling that foolish is simply direspectful. *"Today I would humbly ask you to add something to the accounts of those who left us."* - What if the user and their loved ones wouldn't _want_ something like this being done? This whole FR needs far more thought put into it.

Comment: @Nick when I say Facebook foolishness, I mean them using the fact that you died to raise more money of your memories. for the family part you are right I did not think about that. as I said I'm not the right person for this type of ideas. it just that there is 10 people here who really changed my life by just responding to a question.

Comment: Ah yes, Rudy the dentist.  So many puns and jokes.  I miss him:)

Comment: @Nasreddine it'll sound cheesy but... paying it forward is a GREAT way to keep their memory alive :). They taught you for free and inspired you. Inspire others and help :).  (also, if I remember correctly..... the "people influenced" in your profile was created specifically because of such a situation, no?)