How should I notify you that a user has died?
As it says in the title.
How should I notify you that a user has died?
What then happens to their profile and their content?

As is this wrote, it is something that you should ask using the Contact Us link at bottom of any SO page.

There is a duplicate from 2019, but I'm not sure if it is still up to date: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386951/what-happens-to-an-account-after-you-die. Probably best to use the contact us form and submit prove that you are allowed to manage their digital heritage.

See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38742/how-should-a-users-death-be-handled

If this is not a hypothetical question:  My sincere condoleances to the family of that user.
